# Is it okay to call CloseClipboard() function more than once?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, mfc, clipboard

Depending on certain conditions CloseClipBoard() function can get called twice. Is this okay or will it cause unintended bugs?

ex..

```
void Foo ()
{
    if (::IsClipboardFormatAvailable(clipFormat) && OpenClipboard())
    {
        PasteGridText(clipText);
    }   ::CloseClipboard();
}

BOOL PasteGridText (LPCTSTR text)
{
    ResetClipboardFeedback();..

    if (error)
   {
       **CloseClipboard();**
   }

   return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Unlikely? We don't know the context of your program.

Comment: i wanted to keep it simple so that why I don't give context. 
If there is an error I will need to display a dialog box waiting for user input. i do not want to disable the clipboard functionality throughout the computer so i release the clipboard before displaying the dialog.

Comment: The documentation says nothing about that. It might me ok to call the function twice or it may be not. If in doubt, I'd call it only once.

Comment: If this code happens to be called from a place where the clipboard has already been opened then you are in trouble. Why don't you just do it right instead of attempting to break the rules?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  good idea i Should do that. Its crunch time so i am not thinking clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, yes you can call CloseClipboard() twice without any real consequences.

Here's a test I ran:

```
        bool ocb = OpenClipboard(hwnd);

        if(!ocb)
            printf("Failed to open ClipBoard!\n");
        else
            printf("ClipBoard opened!\n");

        bool ccb = CloseClipboard();

        if(!ccb)
            printf("Failed to close ClipBoard! Error: %lu\n", GetLastError());
        else
            printf("Closed the ClipBoard!\n");

        ccb = CloseClipboard();

        if(!ccb)
            printf("Failed to close ClipBoard! Error: %lu\n", GetLastError());
        else
            printf("Closed the ClipBoard!\n");
```

The results:

```
ClipBoard opened!
Closed the ClipBoard!
Failed to close ClipBoard! Error: 1418

ERROR_CLIPBOARD_NOT_OPEN
1418 (0x58A)
Thread does not have a clipboard open.
```

However, like mentioned in the comments to your question, it's good practice to call CloseClipboard only once for every time you call OpenClipboard. I recommend sticking to that convention.

Comment: What if the code runs when thee clipboard is opened by the caller

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If you're referring to my code above, that code was simply used to help answer the question by providing a demonstration.